# How to split stl file to certain parts if there is too much geometry?

Tags: vertices, wireframe, stl

Im new in blender. Im using it like for a month now and have been focused on rendering fencing stuff like gates, wicket doors etc. but in the past they were supposed to be one colour and stl files i was using were exported without any additional parts like door handles, bolts, screws etc. so it was easier because i didnt have to separate all these parts from the gate. But right now i have a stl file that was exported with all these additional parts and i have to change the colour of those so i need to separate them somehow from that gate so i can change their colour to metallic. I was trying to do it by going in to edit mode, then selecting wireframe mode and selecting parts i want to split using "b" on the keyboard. Then separating by selection. The problem is this stl file was exported in AutoCAD i think and it has so much internal geometry. For example if i separate the post from the gate it still leaves like a half of the screw inside the gate and it takes hours to separate it correctly. I only want to render it for a visualisation so my render doesnt have to be 100% perfect (it is not going to factory and its not technical drawing) but i still dont want it to be so messy. Do you guys know any way i can separate these parts from the main object?[image: here is the screenshot from solid, object mode and wireframe in edit mode]

Comment: "*i have to change the colour of those so i need to separate them somehow*" https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: In Edit mode, try hovering the mouse over the part that you need to isolate and pressing 'L'. If you're lucky that will select just the section you're interested in and you can seperate it with 'P' or add and assign a colour to it.

Comment: You can select a part of the mesh then press Ctrl + L to select all the rest and then separate by selection. Also you can separate all directly by select all the mesh, press P and select separate "All by loose parts"